# Order of batch, prefetch, shuffle and cache in a Tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

When creating a dataset from a generator, what would be the correct order of the following dataset methods? Or does the order not matter here?

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(my_generator)
ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE).shuffle(1000).batch(128).cache()
```

Here I use `prefetch` to speed up data generation and `cache` to avoid calculating after every epoch.

Comment: The comments on the PR can provide some insights: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/18160

Comment: If you cache after shuffling, your data order will be the same between your epochs.

Comment: @Lescurel If I remove the cache, will the learning process be slower because data is generated after each epoch and not cached? Should I move the cache before the shuffle.

Comment: Yes, you can move the cache before the shuffle. Data generation will be slower (because you need to reshuffle at each generation), but you ensure that your data is shuffled between each epoch.